# Why do my passion fruit flowers lack pollen?

Tags: flowers, vines, pollination

I have a passion fruit plant that is about 4 years old, and all the fruit it ever given were two little cracked marbles that fell off the plant quickly.

I water it regularly, I attempted to water it more and sometimes less to see if it changes anything.

I recently noticed that flowers on other passion fruit have a lot of yellow pollen on them, and mine don't have any at all (Seriously, not even a slight bit)

What could cause this? should I try giving it a specific fertilizer? or should I just pull it out?

Comment: It probably did have pollen, just none when you looked - it obviously does produce some, or you wouldn't even have had your two cracked marbles. Where's it growing (pot or ground, in sun or not)? What condition is the foliage in - healthy or poor? Photo would be good too...

Answer (score 3):

If you're watering the plant regularly then it is likely to be the PH of the soil. Passion fruit like a more acidic soil, a good does of chook manure should help, spent coffee grounds are also effective.

If there is any yellowing in the leaves then you'll want some Iron chelate watered in around the root zone.

Some passion fruit are sold as grafted plants, worst case your plant my just be the rootstock where the fruiting graft has died off. If the plant is healthy you may be able to graft a known good fruiter onto your healthy rootstock.